# Файлобменная сеть для программиста

Tags: c#, .net

Пишу программу на C#. Суть программы в скачивании определенных компонентов, таких как например: .Net Framework.

Я файлы для скачивания заливаю на Google Drive
Скачивание проходит хорошо но при скачивании страдает progressBar так как при отправке запроса, обработчик обрабатывает только нулевое значение и 100

```
void WebClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DownloadProgressBar.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
    DownloadProgressBar.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
}
```

Я так понял проблема в Google Drive
Хотел спросить может кто подскажет хороший файлобменник который дает прямые ссылки на скачку, или может кто подскажет как скачивать с того же microsoft на прямую нужные компоненты.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262698/5045688

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.